# JS - Dropdown element dependent

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have the user pick "YES" and the other dropdown automatically goes to "NO" and vice versa. I have a code below, I'm not sure why it is not working.

*I'm trying to get it onload so it automatically runs without the user having to press a button.

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
      <script>
        const cmicrophone = document.querySelector('.select1');
        const microphone = document.querySelector('.select2');

        function inputHandler(thisSelect, otherSelect) {
          // console.log(thisSelect.selectedIndex)
          if (thisSelect.selectedIndex == 1) {
            otherSelect.selectedIndex = 1;
          } else if (thisSelect.selectedIndex == 2) {
            otherSelect.selectedIndex = 2;
          } else {
            thisSelect.selectedIndex = 0;
            otherSelect.selectedIndex = 0;
          }
        }

        cmicrophone.addEventListener('input', event => {
          inputHandler(cmicrophone, microphone);
        });

        microphone.addEventListener('input', event => {
          inputHandler(microphone, cmicrophone);
        });
      </script>

      <div class="cmicrophone" id="cmicrophone">Currently:
        <select id="cmicrophone" class="cmicrophone select1" name="cmicrophone" onchange="">
          <option value="">Select Option</option>
          <option value="'S microphone is currently on. Please remind them to turn it ">YES</option>
          <option value="'S microphone is currently off. Please remind them to turn it ">NO</option>
        </select>
      </div>        
      <div class="microphone" id="microphone">Microphone:
        <select id="microphone" class="microphone select2" name = "microphone">
          <option value=" "  selected="selected"> </option>
          <option value="ON. Thank you.">ON</option>
          <option value="OFF. Thank you.">OFF</option>
        </select>
      </div>    

      <div class="button updatebutton">
        <button onclick="inputHandler(thisSelect, otherSelect)">UPDATE</button>
      </div>                
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` is unique  so try with `class` name .you should apply the class name in two `select` boxes.And

> 1. s1 is `yes` s2 is `on`
> 2. s1 is `No` s2 is `OFF`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="start()">
<script>
function start(){
const cmicrophone = document.querySelector('.select1');
  const microphone = document.querySelector('.select2');

  function inputHandler(thisSelect, otherSelect) {
    // console.log(thisSelect.selectedIndex)
    if (thisSelect.selectedIndex == 1) {
   otherSelect.selectedIndex = 1;
    } else if (thisSelect.selectedIndex == 2) {
   otherSelect.selectedIndex = 2;
    } else {
   thisSelect.selectedIndex = 0;
   otherSelect.selectedIndex = 0;
    }
  }

  cmicrophone.addEventListener('input', event => {
    inputHandler(cmicrophone, microphone);
  });

  microphone.addEventListener('input', event => {
    inputHandler(microphone, cmicrophone);
  });
    }

</script>
    <div class="cmicrophone" id="cmicrophone">Currently:
     <select id="cmicrophone" class="cmicrophone select1" name="cmicrophone" onchange="">
      <option value="">Select Option</option>
      <option value="'S microphone is currently on. Please remind them to turn it ">YES</option>
      <option value="'S microphone is currently off. Please remind them to turn it ">NO</option>
     </select>
    </div>  
    <div class="microphone" id="microphone">Microphone:
     <select id="microphone" class="microphone select2" name = "microphone">
      <option value=" "  selected="selected"> </option>
      <option value="ON. Thank you.">ON</option>
      <option value="OFF. Thank you.">OFF</option>
     </select>
    </div> 

<div class="button updatebutton">
    <button onclick="inputHandler(thisSelect, otherSelect)">UPDATE</button>
   </div>    
   </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

for more simplified of function use this

```
function inputHandler(thisSelect, otherSelect) {
otherSelect.selectedIndex = thisSelect.selectedIndex;
        }
```

***updated answer with single page html***

> They error are placing wrong place of `js script`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


    <div class="cmicrophone" id="cmicrophone">Currently:
     <select id="cmicrophone" class="cmicrophone select1" name="cmicrophone" onchange="">
      <option value="">Select Option</option>
      <option value="'S microphone is currently on. Please remind them to turn it ">YES</option>
      <option value="'S microphone is currently off. Please remind them to turn it ">NO</option>
     </select>
    </div>  
    <div class="microphone" id="microphone">Microphone:
     <select id="microphone" class="microphone select2" name = "microphone">
      <option value=" "  selected="selected"> </option>
      <option value="ON. Thank you.">ON</option>
      <option value="OFF. Thank you.">OFF</option>
     </select>
    </div> 

<div class="button updatebutton">
    <button onclick="inputHandler(thisSelect, otherSelect)">UPDATE</button>
   </div>    
   </form>
  </div>
    <script>
const cmicrophone = document.querySelectorAll('.select1')[0];
const microphone = document.querySelectorAll('.select2')[0];
function inputHandler(thisSelect, otherSelect) {
 otherSelect.selectedIndex =thisSelect.selectedIndex
        }
        cmicrophone.addEventListener('change', event => {
    inputHandler(cmicrophone, microphone);
  });

  microphone.addEventListener('change', event => {
    inputHandler(microphone, cmicrophone);
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do I need to call anything? jquery? It doesn't work for me still not sure what I'm doing that's wrong.

Comment: no need a `jquery ` .copy my code and paste your html.. its working..where error take place could you tell?

Comment: I updated my code with what I copied from yours. the error when I try to run the code snippet is:   "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 30,
  "colno": 14
}

Comment: Are you sure `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" ` is there in above snippet ? But in my view is not there.snippet was running smooth ..please copy both js and html code ..i was edited html code also

Comment: the code I have in my question is the updated code, which is yours of course. when I run it that error occurs. I used the more simplified function {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: thisSelect is not defined",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 38,
  "colno": 74
}

Comment: @catung555555 see my update answer.i think it enough for you

Comment: why put js after not before? I'm just curious

Comment: @catung555555 because content  was not ready to pass js.so use with after. or use inside `window.load = function(){//your js code}` .see my updated answer i was edited both mode js .and single page html. don't forget toe give +1 and  mark as a answer

Answer (score 0):

You should remove ids from divs and change a little bit your start logic like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);

        function ready() {
            const cmicrophone = document.querySelector('#cmicrophone');
            const microphone = document.querySelector('#microphone');

            function inputHandler(thisSelect, otherSelect) {
                console.log(thisSelect.options[thisSelect.selectedIndex].value);
              if (thisSelect.selectedIndex == 1) {
                otherSelect.selectedIndex = 2;
              } else if (thisSelect.selectedIndex == 2) {
                otherSelect.selectedIndex = 1;
              } else {
                thisSelect.selectedIndex = 0;
                otherSelect.selectedIndex = 0;
              }
            }

            cmicrophone.addEventListener('input', event => {
              inputHandler(cmicrophone, microphone);
            });

            microphone.addEventListener('input', event => {
              inputHandler(microphone, cmicrophone);
            });

        }
    </script>
    <div class="cmicrophone">Currently:
        <select id="cmicrophone" class="cmicrophone" name="cmicrophone">
            <option value="">Select Option</option>
            <option value="'S microphone is currently on. Please remind them to turn it ">YES</option>
            <option value="'S microphone is currently off. Please remind them to turn it ">NO</option>
        </select>
    </div>      
    <div class="microphone">Microphone:
        <select id="microphone" class="microphone" name = "microphone">
            <option value=" "  selected="selected"> </option>
            <option value="ON. Thank you.">ON</option>
            <option value="OFF. Thank you.">OFF</option>
        </select>
    </div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/t5ma1c4h/28/)

```
<html>
<body>    
                <div class="cmicrophone" id="cmicrophone">Currently:
                    <select id="cmicrophone" class="cmicrophone select1" name="cmicrophone" onchange="">
                        <option value="">Select Option</option>
                        <option value="'S microphone is currently on. Please remind them to turn it ">YES</option>
                        <option value="'S microphone is currently off. Please remind them to turn it ">NO</option>
                    </select>
                </div>      
                <div class="microphone" id="microphone">Microphone:
                    <select id="microphone" class="microphone select2" name = "microphone">
                        <option value=" "  selected="selected"> </option>
                        <option value="ON. Thank you.">ON</option>
                        <option value="OFF. Thank you.">OFF</option>
                    </select>
                </div>  

<div class="button updatebutton">
                <button onclick="inputHandler(thisSelect, otherSelect)">UPDATE</button>
            </div>              
            </form>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    change1('YES')
    change2('OFF')
});

function change1(text1)
{
  $("#cmicrophone option").filter(function() {    
    //may want to use $.trim in here
      return $(this).text() == text1; 
  }).prop('selected', true);
}

function change2(text2)
{
    $("#microphone option").filter(function() {
    //may want to use $.trim in here
    return $(this).text() == text2; 
    }).prop('selected', true);
}

$('#cmicrophone').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).text() == 'YES') {
    change2('ON')
    //$('.elem').not(this).val('off');
  } else {
    //$('.elem').not(this).val('on');
    change2('OFF')
  }
});


$('#microphone').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).text() == 'ON') {
    change1('NO')
    //$('.elem').not(this).val('off');
  } else {
    //$('.elem').not(this).val('on');
    change1('YES')
  }
});
```

Comment: just change the function names to start with lowercase, to follow js conventions.